# List view disappears on moving to another activity from list view

Tags: android, android-listview, android-activity

I am facing some weird problem where when I move from `Activity 1` to `Activity 2` list view that is in activity 1 automatically **disappears** to see the list view again I need to again start `Activity 1`.

I am going to activity 2 from `button` in list view of activity 1.

I don't understand this behavior and I am unsure of problem and solution as well.

Code below:

Activity 1:

```
public class stockmanager extends Activity{
    
    String getentry;
    private int storeID=0;
    //Database d;
    StockTable st;
    StockList sl;
    Database d;
    private String getstocks;
    public Cursor a1;
    Intent bd;
    Intent sd;
    String s,AllStocks;
    private String deletestock_sl,deletestock_st;
     TextView displaystocks;
     ListView popstocks;
     poplist populatestocks;
     int stockid;
     Cursor getid;
        
    static class ViewHolder {
        
        CheckBox cb;
        Button view1; 
    }
        
    
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.stockmanager);
        
        d=new Database(getApplicationContext());
        st=new StockTable(getApplicationContext());
        sl=new StockList(getApplicationContext());
        
        
        new Dboperation().execute();
        
        
    }
    public class poplist extends CursorAdapter{

        
        public poplist(Context context, Cursor c) {
            super(context, c);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
        

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor c) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
            final ViewHolder myviewholder=new ViewHolder();
            myviewholder.cb=(CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            myviewholder.view1=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1); 
            
            
            myviewholder.cb.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(sl.Column2)));
                
            
            myviewholder.cb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    
                    if(myviewholder.cb.isChecked())
                    {
                        a.add((String) myviewholder.cb.getText());
                        
                    }
                    
                }
            });
            
            myviewholder.view1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                
                    sd=new Intent(v.getContext(),Detail.class);
                    sd.putExtra("StockName", myviewholder.cb.getText());
                    
                    startActivity(sd);      //Activity 2 triggered here
                     
                    
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stocklist, parent, false);
                    bindView(v, context, c);
                   return v;
//          return null;
        }
        
        
    }
    
private class Dboperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Cursor>{

        ProgressDialog pd;
        @Override
        protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    
            a1=Database.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(sl.getstocks, null);
            
            return a1;
        }

        
        protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
            if(a1.moveToNext())
            {
                displaystocks.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            else
            {
                displaystocks.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            //System.out.println("Entered onpostexecute");  
            final poplist populatestocks=new poplist(getApplicationContext(),a1) ;
            popstocks.setAdapter(populatestocks);
            
            if(pd!=null)
                pd.dismiss();
            
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        
            pd=new ProgressDialog(stockmanager.this);
            pd.setMessage("Please wait.... Loading Data");
            pd.show(); 
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        }

                
    }

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onDestroy();
if(a1!=null){
    a1.close();
}
if(Database.getInstance(getApplicationContext())!=null){
    Database.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).close();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    if(a1!=null){
        a1.close();
    }
    if(Database.getInstance(getApplicationContext())!=null){
        Database.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).close();
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior.  The [Documentation for Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) should help you out in this case.  This link should tell you everything you need to know about why you've seen this behavior.

While it is possible to have two activities visible to the user simultaneously, I rarely see this done using anything other than Fragments, and I would not recommend it in general.  If what you want is to pop up a window on button click that displays new data, then you probably should instead use something like a Layout that toggles its visibility, or perhaps a Dialog.

Comment: Thanks for your response... if this is the normal behaviour.. then can I again call `ASync task` in `onResume`. Is this is suggested approach..